# Making an application with Python and PHP and HTML on Google's app Engine

Tags: php, python, mysql, google-app-engine

I am switching from servers in AWS to [google-app-engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs). They suggest using different setups for different code bases (as seen below). My application uses `Python` webscraping, and has a database which is talked to by `PHP`. The `Python` is rather intensive computationally, so I really need to prioritize the computation speed in that department, but can I run `PHP` code with a `mysql` database effectively on webapp2 or Jinja2?

Exerpt from google's website:

In Python with webapp2 and Jinja2.

In Java with maven.

In PHP with Cloud SQL.

In Go with the html/template package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different runtimes (PHP/Python etc.) in different modules.

You can also configure the performance characteristics of each module individually in the relevant .yaml file

Module reference:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/

Comment: Thank you, this definitely got me looking in the right direction.